# How to include additional files and directory in egg while deploying Scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I have Scrapy project, I want it to deploy it using `scrapyd-deploy` or `scrapy deploy` command line tool. It went well, but notice that it doesn't include additional file in package. For example I have a file sources/sourcelist.csv in spider directory. But it doesn't seems to include package. How can I force deploy script to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short you can include additional files using `scrapy deploy`. But in long, you can. You have to create egg yourself and upload that egg.

First, Create your egg. Create or edit setup.py that exists in your project root. It should look like below:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = ozbot.settings']},
    include_package_data = True
)
```

Notice `include_package_data = True` line.

Second, create distribution egg.

```
$python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Third, deploy the egg

```
$scrapy deploy dist/your_egg_file.egg
```

Make sure you replace `your_egg_file.egg` with right file name